# Etymology of "bridge" (the card game)

Tags: etymology, historical-change, origin-unknown

I've always thought that the name of this card game comes from the English word *bridge* (the structure) but it is not quite like that. It's the English pronunciation of a game called *Biritch*, which was also known as *Russian Whist*.

Etymology of the word from [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bridge):

> card game, 1886 (perhaps as early as 1843), an alteration of **biritch**, but the source and meaning of that are obscure. "Probably of Levantine origin, since some form of the game appears to have been long known in the Near East" [OED]. One guess is that it represents **Turkish *bir-üç "one-three,"** because one hand is exposed and three are concealed. The game also was known early as Russian whist (attested in English from 1839).

Furthermore from the book "The Theory of Gambling and Statistical Logic" *By Richard A. Epstein*:

[image: The initial progenitor of all Bridge forms is the game of Triumph, which gained currency about A.D. 1500. In the mid-seventeenth century, Triumph evolved into Whist(1), a partnership game for four players. The change from Whist to Bridge occurred about 1886 with the publication in London of a small pamphlet, titled "Biritch," or "Russian Whist." This title created the fallacy that Bridge is of Russian origin(2). In actually, while the precise etymology cannot be traced with assurance, the word has likely evolved from a Levantine source.]

[image: (1) The English lawyer Edmond Hoyle produced a world titled "A Short Treatise on Whist," which led to his position as the panjandrum of game rules. (2) The word "Biritch" is not a recognized Russian word, however liberal be the retransliteration to Cyrillic. The Russians did play a card game called "Ieralashch" resembling short Whist without a trump suit. From this game are derived "Siberia" and "Preference," which share certain characteristics with Bridge.]

---

**Question**

This is the furthest I can go in my research (looks like an answer already) but is it possible to go further? Even it says obscure, are there any sources that goes deeper and gives more details (for the following questions especially)?

**Related questions:**

- Why is the word corrupted to a word — *bridge* — that is already used? For
  example, why not *britch*? Is there a folk etymology here?
- How come there is a Levantine and Turkish origin? Can it be that
  Russians learned this game from Ottomans in the era of wars, or did they adopt a name from the Ottoman Turkish language? (Also, the passage from the source book mentions that *Biritch* is not a recognized Russian word.)

---

**Note:** "Biritch" does not sound like a mispronunciation of some Turkish word or phrase meaning *no trump*. Interestingly, a Turkish language etymology website says that the name of this game *briç* is a loan word from English *bridge*. But this is about the modern Turkish language; there is also the Ottoman Turkish language used at that time which I can't trace back.

Comment: Tip: avoid posting thought provoking or challenging questions on a Sunday.

Comment: I'd be curious to know if *biritch* was played by the Russian aristocracy and if their British peers adopted the card game. I think this question is probably better suited to [HistorySE](http://history.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Mari-Lou: it probably originated as a Turkish variation of Whist; it was called *"Russian whist"* because it was played by the Russian colony in Constantinople; see my answer.

Comment: I think this website: [The origins and history of bridge](http://www.ebu.co.uk/origins-and-history-of-bridge) might be of interest. I would post an answer myself... but I've never played a game of *bridge* in my life.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: What's wrong with Sunday? If you think that it gets less attention, I might think of placing a bounty on it later. I also thought of History and Linguistics stackexchange but this is a bit of mixture of topics.

Comment: Haven't you noticed? The number of questions and the resulting activity online drops. It makes sense, people will either sleep in, or... actually leave their computers and go out, omg!

Comment: The use of "bridge" rather than "britch" seems similar to me to the voicing of the final consonant that occurs for some speakers in words like *ostrich, sandwich, Greenwich*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some of your questions are answered by [*this website*,](http://www.pagat.com/boston/biritch.html) which contains a transcription of the original pamphlet describing *biritch*. Collison (the author of the pamphlet, and a railroad engineer who worked for a time in Turkey) apparently wrote a letter to *The Saturday Review* dated 28 May 1906, where he describes the history of the game.  I quote:

> Between 1880-4 I spent a considerable time in Constantinople and Asia Minor, where I played what was then called 'Biritch or Russian Whist'. I was then living, while in England, at Cromwell Road and introduced the game to many of my English friends, who liked it so much that they asked me to have the rules printed. ... 'Biritch' was attributed to the Russian colony at Constantinople; in my time the dominating social and political element.    [not my ellipses, but the website's]

There were many variations of whist played in Russia, which this game was similar to. Mari-Lou in the comments has found a source that showing *biritch* is a variation of an earlier Russian game called *yeralash*. So while it's not clear whether the word *biritch* was originally Russian, most of the rules of the game are.

The word *"biritch"* means (in the game) *no trump*, although it is unclear whether this meaning is connected to its etymology. Maybe somebody who knows Turkish could tell us whether *biritch* might be a Russian mispronunciation of some word or phrase meaning *"no trump"*.

More information probably can be found in the original version of *The Saturday Review* letter and also in another reference given on the above website: Thierry Depaulis and Jac Fuchs, "First Steps of Bridge in the West: Collinson's 'Biritch'", The Playing-Card, Vol. 32, no. 2, Sep.-Oct. 2003, pp. 67-76. Unfortunately, I can find neither of these online.

Comment: There is an online repository of much of [*The Saturday Review*](http://www.unz.org/Pub/SaturdayRev) but not 1906. Those interested in *The Playing Card* might want to [join IPCS](http://i-p-c-s.org/) which publishes it in order to get access to back issues.

Comment: There's a pdf file which has more info on its history https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CE8QFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnewinbridge.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fnews%2Fpdf%2Fjarolasch.pdf&ei=luCBU7KXBcmB7QbD94C4DQ&usg=AFQjCNEX5Ms8WtbKYsHIq0aVhxlmnu_BYA&sig2=nJIO8IODE9lGF_PYg6MWtw and this website says: ["it was not until 1742 that the first book devoted to whist appeared: Edmond Hoyles famous Short Treatise on Whist"](http://www.ebu.co.uk/origins-and-history-of-bridge)

Comment: @Mari-Lou: nice find. So *biritch* takes many of its rules from a Russian version of whist, *yeralash*. And the main rule change from *yeralash* is the existence of the dummy, which makes the etymology of *birich* deriving from Turkish *bir-üç* ("one-three") seem more likely. In googling 19th century source, it appears that the name *Russian whist* was used not only for *birich* and *yeralash* but also *vint*, another whist-like game popular in Russia.

Comment: @Peter: "Biritch" does not sound like a mispronunciation of some Turkish word or phrase meaning "no trump". Interestingly,  a Turkish language etymology website says that the name of this game "briç" is a loan word from English "bridge". But this is about modern Turkish language, there is also Ottoman Turkish language used at that time which I can't trace back.

Comment: Dalton, William. 1906. "Saturday" Bridge: Reproduced with Revisions from the "Saturday Review.” London. The West Strand Publisihing Co. [a collection, with a bibliography, of the author’s (unsigned) articles in The Saturday Review of Politics, Literature, Science, and Art; the collection was revised several times, lastly in 1912].

Comment: Dalton’s four articles originally appeared in The Saturday Review on 19 May 1906 (pp. 618-619), 26 May 1906 (p. 654-655), 2 June (p. 689), and 9 June 1906 (p. 722). They are gathered in chapter 2 (“The Evolution of Bridge”) of the above-mentioned collection.

Comment: The full run for the year 1906 of The Saturday Review may be seen on this website of the Hathitrust:  https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044092859602&view=1up&seq=627&size=125&q1=collinson

Comment: This article is now available online (in full and free of charge):Depaulis, Thierry, and Jac Fuchs. 2003. "First Steps of Bridge in the West: Collinson's 'Biritch'." The Playing-Card: Journal of the International Playing-Card Society. Vol. 32. No. 2. September-October. Pp. 67-76 [https://www.academia.edu/29041440/_First_Steps_of_Bridge_in_the_West_Collinsons_Biritch_The_Playing_Card_vol_32_no_2_Sept_Oct_2003_pp_67_76].

Answer (score 4):

About biritch/ biryutch: the word was not widely used (it was scarce, in fact), but what Wikipedia said is wrong. The word can be found in the Russian dictionary of Vladimir Dal (a recognized dictionary) of 1863-1866 (and reissues). The problem comes from the fact that around 1900 the bridge authority Robert Frederic Foster (after William Dalton, another bridge expert) said that the word "biritch" was not a Russian word. Neither made extensive research.

Note also that in Romanian the word "britch" exists, but the meaning is "razor", without relation to a game.

I don't assert 100% that the name of *Bridge* or *Britch* (its old name) comes from the Russian word "Biritch", but this is the more probable explanation.

Comment: Philbod = Philippe Bodard, who is one of the authors of the following article (and is therefore someone whose statements should be given serious consideration):  Beauchêne, Gérard, Philippe Bodard, Jean-Louis Counil, and Thierry Depaulis. 2011. “From ‘britch’ to ‘bridge’; early French accounts of the 1800’s and 1890’s.” The Playing-Card. Vol. 40. No. 1. July-September. Pp. 20-31.

Answer (score 1):

- "Russian whist" is only a "gnosis", used by Collinson, to explain the word "Biritch". Of course, all the different whists from Russia are also "Russian whist" : yeralash, vint, preference....
- Biritch is also an old russian word. The pronunciation is "britch". The meaning is "announcer".
- The contribution of Turkey in the all history of card games is absolutely insignificant
- The "Biritch" game, is an evolution of the Russian game of yeralash (notrump), with an Austrian contribution, the double ("Kontra" in german), and a French contribution, the dummy (which is mandatory in Biritch, not in yeralash)(it was in France that the dummy was very popular)
- the word "bridge" (the game) is a corruption of britch (same pronunciation)
- The biritch/britch game came in Constantinople about 1873 from Romania (two proofs) (and before from Austria and Russia)
- Greeks were at the origin of the introduction of the game of "Britch" in UK (before 1880) and in France.

Comment: Do you have a source for all these facts? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biritch) says that the word *birich* was last used in Russian around 1700. Could it have been the source of the name of a card game which couldn't have been invented before 1850 or so?

Comment: but wikipedia is not even a joke.

Comment: Can anyone verify the following bibliographical reference? The problem is "IMP," which among players of bridge stands for 'internal match points': Secelle, Hans, and Bob van de Velde.  2011. “De (her)ontdekking van een missing link; Jarolasch, directe voorvader van Bridge.” IMP. Vol. 22. No. 7. October-November. Pp. 6-10. Is the full official name of the publication (1) IMP, (2) International Match Points, or (3) something else?

Comment: Can anyone give a full bibliographical reference for the following article, which is available on  the Web, but with absolutely no indication of who its author is, when and where it was published, etc.? It must have appeared in Belgium or in The Netherlands.“INTERMEZZO 1: OORSPRONG EN ONTWIKKELING VAN HET BRIDGESPEL”

Answer (score 1):

Walther von Wartburg, the Swiss philologist, provides the following information in the entry for *bridge* of the *Französisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch* (the Kleinschreibung is Wartburg's):

> - Dieses spiel ist russischen ursprungs.  So erschien noch 1886 in England ein traktat *Biritch or Russian Whist*.  Dieses russische spiel wurde zum ersten mal 1873 von Westeuropäern in Konstantinopel, wo sie tätig waren, gespielt.  Vor allem war es der italienische diplomat Graziani, der es einführte.  Das spiel verbreitete sich rasch in der eleganten kosmopolitischen gesellschaft in Athen, in Ägypten, an der Riviera, und dann nach USA, von wo es um 1890 nach Frankreich gelangt ist.  Russisch *bric* wurde als *bridge* ins englische aufgenommen, und dieses drang dann in die andern sprachen ein.  Dass das wort mit *bridge* „brücke” identifiziert wurde, zeigt sich daran, dass es im italienischen einige zeit *ponte* genannt wurde.

My translation:

> - The game is of Russian origin.  A treatise called *Biritch or Russian Whist* was published in England in 1886.  This Russian game was played for the first time in 1873 by West Europeans active in Constantinople.  It was introduced in particular by the Italian diplomat Graziani.  The game spread quickly in the elegant and cosmopolitan circles of Athens, Egypt and the Riviera, and then to the United States, from where it came to France around 1890.  Russian *bric* was loaned as *bridge* into English, which then made its way into the other languages.  That the word was identified with *bridge* meaning *brücke*, *pons*, can be seen in the fact that for a while it was called *ponte* in Italian.

Comment: Von Wartburg's "traktat" (treatise) is an exaggeration. Collinson’s pamphlet consists of four pages measuring about three by five inches.

See the full text here:
https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Biritch,_or_Russian_Whist